# AUTO INCREMENT after INSERT changing previously inserted value

Tags: mysql

I've been working with mysql at work for a few years, and I never seen such a strange behaviour, so I am very surprised.

I am replicating the Drupal installation for a pet project of mine from my hosting site (FastComet) on my laptop. I made a dump of the database from cPanel (MySQL 8.0.31 Community) and brought it on my laptop (MariaDB 10.6.11).

I changed all the occurrences of `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` in the dump file to `utf8mb4_general_ci`, then I did my usual command sequence for restoring a DB,

```
mysql -e 'drop database fcdrupal'
mysql -e 'create database fcdrupal CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
mysql fcdrupal < dumpfile.sql
```

I got strange behaviours from Drupal indicating the absence of the anonymous users, so I checked on the database and I found

```
MariaDB [fcdrupal]> select * from users ;
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
| uid | uuid                                 | langcode |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
|   1 | 2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7 | en       |
|  17 | 31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5 | en       |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,000 sec)
```

while in the dump file I see

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`uid`, `uuid`, `langcode`) VALUES
(0, '31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5', 'en'),
(1, '2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7', 'en');
```

I did a `grep users` on the dump file, and I didn't find any `UDATE`; only at the very end there is a suspicious

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `uid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
```

Indeed, if I change 17 to 13 and I run everything again, the entry for user 0 gets uid=13.

The definition of the columns for the table is the following:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uuid     | varchar(128) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| langcode | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Of course I can easily fix this problem, but at the end of the dump file there is a bunch of similar `ALTER TABLE` with similar auto increments, and I'm afraid they may break something else. And I'd like to understand what's going on, anyway.

EDIT: here is a full text on MariaDB 10.6.11 showing what happens with pure SQL commands:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create database test ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use test ;
Database changed
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE `users` (
    ->   `uid` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `uuid` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `langcode` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci COMMENT='The base table for user entities.';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,008 sec)

MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `users` (`uid`, `uuid`, `langcode`) VALUES
    -> (0, '31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5', 'en'),
    -> (1, '2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7', 'en');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,004 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select * from users ;
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
| uid | uuid                                 | langcode |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
|   0 | 31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5 | en       |
|   1 | 2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7 | en       |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> ALTER TABLE `users`
    ->   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
    ->   ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_field__uuid__value` (`uuid`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,015 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> ALTER TABLE `users`
    ->   MODIFY `uid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,015 sec)              
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select * from users ;
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
| uid | uuid                                 | langcode |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
|   1 | 2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7 | en       |
|  13 | 31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5 | en       |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,002 sec)
```

I cannot understand how the `ALTER TABLE` can modify the inserted data.

Comment: I'm testing with MySQL 8.0.31 and it does not include those ALTER TABLE statements in the mysqldump output. Could this be a change in the mysqldump tool included with the MariaDB distribution? I don't use MariaDB.

Comment: In general, it's good advice to always use the same brand and version of software in development as you will use in production. MariaDB and MySQL are not the same product, or even compatible anymore. You should switch your laptop to MySQL if that's what you use on your hosted server.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I agree that it is advisable to use alway the same version of the database in development and production – but here we are talking about a simple pet project, where I use what I have available. Anyway , on one hand I removed an option on the export and I managed to get rid of those `ALTER TABLE`, which solved the problem; on the other, I reduced the question to a series of queries on MariaDB, and I inserted them in the question, maybe now it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

> `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>
> ... When you insert a value of NULL (recommended) or 0 into an indexed AUTO_INCREMENT column, the column is set to the next sequence value.

The row on which you inserted the value 0 got changed to the next auto-increment value.

Before the ALTER TABLE:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
| uid | uuid                                 | langcode |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
|   0 | 31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5 | en       |
|   1 | 2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7 | en       |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
```

After the ALTER TABLE:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
| uid | uuid                                 | langcode |
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
|   1 | 2768f481-9b57-4572-855b-5f12604160e7 | en       |
|  13 | 31d6af76-e761-4f89-a8c0-22efb01d1ce5 | en       | <- was uid 0
+-----+--------------------------------------+----------+
```

The ALTER TABLE effectively re-inserted the rows, and the uid 0 value triggered the generation of a new auto-increment value.

I'm still not sure why the output of your dump from cPanel contained ALTER TABLE statements to add keys to the table. The standard output from mysqldump uses CREATE TABLE to define both the columns and keys.

Comment: I don't understand, why does an `ALTER TABLE` reinsert the rows? O_O

Comment: Concerning your question – there was an option triggering this behaviour on the GUI of phpMyAdmin, something like Object creation options - Add CREATE TABLE - AUTO_INCREMENT value (I'm sorry, I cannot find quickly how to set the language to English so I had to translate myself and the real labels are likely to be different).

Comment: Adding a primary key to a table causes a table copy operation. That is, ALTER TABLE internally makes a new tablespace, copies the rows to it, and then swaps the new tablespace for the old one.

Comment: I had no idea – good to know!